# allow user access to syslog

Tags: sudo, alias, syslog

I'm running an embedded Linux (Dreadnaught), and I'd like to be able to manually enter a line into the syslog as the user login, and have the result of other commands stored in the syslog. e.g.:

```
echo ======== Setting chat and Options for Insys >>/var/log/messages
cat /etc/ppp/options >> /var/log/messages
```

Syslog is initiated in /etc/inittab:

```
::respawn:/sbin/syslogd -n -s 200 -b 2 -S -m0
```

I have some alias' to perform common tasks, and I'd like syslog to be updated when they are run:

```
alias Insys='echo =================== Setting chat and Options for Insys >> /var/log/messages; cp /var/config/tw_con_Insys.lge /var/config/tw_con.lge; cp /etc/ppp/peers/tw_options_Insys /etc/ppp/peers/tw_options; con; echo =================== Complete >> /var/log/messages'
alias setup='echo =================== options ===================; echo ""; echo ""; cat /etc/ppp/options; echo ""; echo ""; echo =================== chat ===================; echo ""; echo ""; cat /var/config/tw_con.lge; echo ""; echo ============================================;'
```

The setup command writes to the terminal, I would like it to write to the syslog instead, i.e. setup>>/var/log/messages.

The problem is that /var/log/messages is owned by root, not user. I can manually run

```
 su -c 'chmod 777 /var/log/messages'
```

, it prompts me for the root pwd, then after this I can run my shortcuts and they work. However, each time the log rolls over to messages.0 and a new messages is created, I've lost the privs and have to run it again.

I tried to create an alias for this chmod so I can run it before I run my custom scripts:

```
alias userlog='su -c ''chmod 777 /var/log/messages'''
```

The alias is accepted, but doesn't run.

```
[user@Dreadnaught_TEP1 etc]$ userlog
su: unknown user 777
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Don't use `>>` to append to the file, use the actual `syslog` command. `man syslog` should tell you more.

Comment: There isn't a syslog command in this build, and syslogd doesn't appear to let me use it as a conduit:`[user@Dreadnaught_TEP1 /sbin]$ echo "============test" |syslogd' did nothing.

Comment: '
[user@Dreadnaught_TEP1 /sbin]$ syslogd -?
syslogd: invalid option -- '?'
BusyBox v1.17.1 (2018-03-05 11:01:55 AEST) multi-call binary.

Usage: syslogd [OPTIONS]

System logging utility.
This version of syslogd ignores /etc/syslog.conf

'

Comment: 'Options:
        -n              Run in foreground
        -O FILE         Log to given file (default:/var/log/messages)
        -l N            Set local log level
        -S              Smaller logging output
        -s SIZE         Max size (KB) before rotate (default:200KB, 0=off)
        -b N            N rotated logs to keep (default:1, max=99, 0=purge)
        -R HOST[:PORT]  Log to IP or hostname on PORT (default PORT=514/UDP)
        -L              Log locally and via network (default is network only if -R)
        -D              Drop duplicates

Comment: -C[size(KiB)]   Log to shared mem buffer (read it using logread)'

Comment: I'm not sure what to do about your alias command, since it appears to have an odd number of single quotes. But it might be better to use the [logger](https://busybox.net/downloads/BusyBox.html#logger) command.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick Thanks! I hadn't found the logger command, looks like it does exactly what I need, and I don't need to chmod the syslog. I had looked through all the commands in sbin, but didn't check bin.

Answer (score 0):

Solved thanks to @MarkPlotnick! the [logger](https://busybox.net/downloads/BusyBox.html#logger) command does what I need, no need for chmod or anything like that.

```
alias Insys='logger =================== Setting chat and Options for Insys ;      cp /var/config/tw_con_Insys.lge /var/config/tw_con.lge;     cp /etc/ppp/peers/tw_options_Insys /etc/ppp/peers/tw_options;     con; logger =================== Complete; setup '
alias setup='logger =================== options ===================; cat /etc/ppp/options | logger; logger =================== chat ===================;  cat /var/config/tw_con.lge | logger; logger ============================================'
```